# Practical Steps to Increase Personal Integrity?

Tags: professionalism, ethics, performance

Hoping this isn't too vague.

**Background:** Working in a larger office, I worry how people perceive me. Perception is everything. With so many people, rumors and misinformation spread like wildfire. I have always taken pride in my work ethic and deliverables, but I am left feeling that my participation in exchanges is brushed off/ignored/deemed unvaluable. When I'm providing input in a formal forum (meetings etc), I am receiving the level of professionalism to be expected. I don't feel that specifics are pertinent, I'm trying to express a general vibe, but two factors that may come into play are; I'm in the youngest 10%, and my education credentials aren't corporate mainstream. Could be that I'm reading into these social situations, or projecting my insecurities. Note that I am *not* socially awkward, and am quite skilled in contributing in casual exchanges (*Listening*, reiterating, etc) . As far as I can read am not alienating myself in the moment.

Regardless of what we do, there will always be those who dismiss or judge us. As I can't control how and what people think of me, but can control my own actions.

**Goal:** to improve my integrity in both work and personal life, ensuring that any negative opinions I receive are unwarranted.

**Question:** What practical actions can we utilize in order to ensure how we are perceived, our practices, and interactions are centered around integrity?

Some of my initial ideas;

**1) Seek to be Honest:** Don't embellish/exaggerate or lie. Owning and rising above  your failures will greatly improves how people percieve you. Take ownership of what you say and how you say it. I've found that the key to honesty starts with replacing all the small lies with small truths. When asked how you are doing, be genuine & appropriate in your answer.

**2) Manage time effectively**: Don't be late to work. Aiming to be at your workspace 10-15 minutes early will ensure that delays don't actually make you late. Be punctual to meetings/calls/etc. Utilize the whole working day and don't sneak off early. Avoid 'time-wasting' activities. Treat everyone's time as the precious commodity it is.

**3) Don't talk ill of anyone:** as much as people migrate towards hot gossip, they have little respect for those providing it. When a person talks ill of a 3rd party to you, it plants the seed they will be talking ill of you the moment you part.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think these are excellent ways to be professional at work. Increasing your *mental strength* may help with the occasional negativity.

Comment: If you aren't already doing all that - how are you going to change your behaviour? And how are you going to overcome an already damaged perception of integrity?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'dismiss[ed]'. Are you concerned that people think of you as: dishonest; lazy; unreliable; slapdash; other?

Comment: @HorusKol for the 3 items that I've listed, these are my current focus for improvement. Not to say that I'm a complete mess in these areas, but when I catch myself failing, will make a mental note to correct next time. For example, I was late to work due to several cascading delays during my commute (I drive an hour into the office). Although I can't always be certain that I will arrive on time, I opted to leave 5 minutes earlier to up the average.

Comment: @HorusKol In regards to improving their perception of me, I'm not sure there is anything I can do directly. In time, if i apply and improve myself eventually I'll win over even the most skewed perception. Have to play the long game.

Comment: @AakashM - Edited background for further clarity

Answer (score 3):

Your initial ideas all seem like good ones and things you should implement. Still this strikes me as something where lack of self confidence could be an issue, much like dating where you can get into vicious/virtuous cycles of I'm not confident so dating goes poorly which dents my confidence etc etc. 
Practically speaking, take a look at the people you admire in your work environment and how they handle themselves -( there's no 'right' answer, it's just the kind of traits you respond to) if you can isolate those things and seek to work on them that'll diminish your insecurity and hopefully get you on a roll

Answer (score 2):

4) Do the work as it is intended to be done.

5) Acknowledge breakdowns; report early. Distinguish what caused the breakdown and what can be changed to prevent a next one. *This has nothing to do with morality*, do not bring/turn it into a good/bad discourse. It is only about workability for everyone.